# No persistence in JBoss Messaging

Tags: jms, persistence, jboss-messaging

I've managed to follow this guide (https://community.jboss.org/thread/129340) to remove persistence from JBoss messaging. Bascially by adding the null-persistence-service.xml and emptying persistence-service.xml.
But if I want to do it for a specific queue and not all queues - how would I go about and do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to do it programmatically like this:

```
producer.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
message.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
```